# How often do apps go on sale in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

Does the App Store regularly run generous discounts similar to Steam or am I just spoiled by random weekly -75% discounts?

In particular, are discounts on the App Store common enough to be worth waiting for, or should I just buy apps mostly at full price instead of waiting half a year for a 20% discount?

Comment: The apple app store itself doesn't have sales.  Sometimes developers themselves change prices down (or up).   I always by pre-paid app store gift certificates which you can regularly find for 15% off, it's good to follow @itunescarddeals on Twitter to watch for the 15% deals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discounts available from time to time are always determined by the software developer. Apple does not set the price of apps, nor the regularity of *discounts* offered by developers. (Apple's own apps excluded of course!)

In other words, one software publisher may offer a discounted price for a week each month, while another may never offer a discount. And, because of the sheer volume of developers, there's no way to identify any meaningful pattern.

However, there are a number of services that allow you to add apps to a *wish list* and then notify you when those apps are discounted. I have listed two below purely as examples:

- [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com)
- [AppZapp](http://www.appzapp.us)

These services also usually give users a historical breakdown of the price charged for an app over its history, so you could use that to get a sense of how often a particular developer is inclined to discount their app(s).

Now, what Apple does discount is their gift cards - electronic and in stores. People often load up on $100 cards for $79 which is more than 20% off and even Wallet was offering $20 off for people using their devices to add value to their accounts. If you know you will spend over time and don’t mind carrying a balance, you can save that way even when developers don’t run sales. It also means other purchases (e.g. music, movies, subscriptions, etc) are purchased at a discount even though Apple, Netflix and others may not offer such discounts directly.

Comment: Thanks. How often on average does this happen in practice? (rough estimate over all significant app developers) Would it be closer to Steam's regular massive discounts or -20% every once on a while?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some extra info that may be useful for you. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: See my comment on the original question for how to save 15%... Works for iCloud storage payments as well.

Comment: @user3439894 I've edited it, plus added to it. Just a friendly reminder though, feel free to edit posts (even those by moderators) yourself. :)